# can't finding B event under not A event in Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The conditional probability Pr[B|A] is 4/5; the conditional probability P[B|not A] is 2/5, and the unconditional probability of B is 1/2. What is the probability of A?

I know P(A) = (P(A/B) * P(B)) / P(B/A)

But I can't know how to get P(B/not A) from these probabilities.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are given $P(B\,|\,A^c)$, you don't need to compute it.

Comment: But you don't needs Bayes' Theorem here...we have $P(B)=P(A)\times P(B\,|\,A)+P(A^c)\times P(B\,|\,A^c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(B)=P(A)P(B|A)+P(\overline {A})P(B|\overline {A})$$

$P(\overline {A})=1-P(A)$

... I think you are all set

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Write the law of total probability for $P(B)$ conditioned on $A$.